# Fill inputs that are generated dynamically with jquery while selecting an option in the select box

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, oop

I have created the GUI that looks like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RUgCm.png)

the code for this part is:

```
<table class="table table-responsive table-bordered table-hover">
   <thead>
      <th>Shërbimi</th>
      <th>Përshkrimi</th>
      <th>Njësia</th>
      <th>Çmimi</th>
      <th>Sasia</th>
      <th>Total</th>
      <th><input type="button" value="+" id="add" class="btn btn-primary"></th>
   </thead>
   <tbody class="detail">
      <tr>
         <td width="25%">
            <select name="service[]" id="sh" class="form-control sherbimi"  aria-describedby="llojisherbimit" required>
               <option selected="selected" value="">Zgjedh Shërbimin</option>
               <?php
                  $service = new \Admin\Lib\Service();
                  $services=$service->find_all();
                  foreach ($services as $s){
                      echo "<option value='".$s->id ."'  class='sale-select' selected='selected'> "
                          .$s->service_name . "</option>";   
                  }
                  ?>
            </select>
            <div class="invalid-feedback">
               Ju lutem plotësoni shërbimin.
            </div>
         </td>
         <td width="30%" >
            <input type="text" id="pershkrimi" value="" class="form-control" name="description[]" required >
            <div class="invalid-feedback">
               Ju lutem plotësoni përshkrimin.
            </div>
         </td>
         <td width="15%">
            <select name="unit[]" class="form-control" aria-describedby="llojinjesis" required>
               <option value="">Zgjedh Njësin</option>
               <option value='cope'> Copë </option>
               <option value='dite'> Ditë </option>
            </select>
            <div class="invalid-feedback">
               Ju lutem plotësoni njësin.
            </div>
         </td>
         <td width="10%"  >
            <input type="text" id="cmimi"  class="form-control price" name="price[]" required>
            <div class="invalid-feedback">
               Ju lutem plotësoni çmimin.
            </div>
         </td>
         <td width="10%">
            <input type="text" class="form-control quantity" name="quantity[]" required>
            <div class="invalid-feedback">
               Ju lutem plotësoni sasinë.
            </div>
         </td>
         <td width="10%">
            <input type="text" class="form-control amount" name="amount[]" required>
            <div class="invalid-feedback">
               Ju lutem plotësoni totalin.
            </div>
         </td>
         <td>
            <!-- <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger a-btn-slide-text remove">
               <span><strong>x</strong></span></a> -->
         </td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
   <tfoot>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th style="text-align:center;" class="total">0<b></b></th>
      <th></th>
   </tfoot>
</table>
```

The rows of the table are generated dynamically with javascript, the code for generating the rows looks like this:

```
function addnewrow()
{
    vartr = '<tr>'+
        '<td><?php
            echo '<select id="sh"  name="service[]" class="form-control sherbimi" aria-describedby="llojisherbimit" required>';
            echo '<option selected="selected" value=""> Zgjedh opsionin </option>';
            $service = new \Admin\Lib\Service();
            $services=$service->find_all();
            foreach ($services as $s){
                echo '<option value="'.$s->id .'"  class="sale-select" selected="selected"> '
                    .$s->service_name. '</option>';
            }
            echo '</select>';
            ?></td>'+
        '<td><input type="text" id="pershkrimi" value="" class="form-control" name="description[]" required ></td>'+

        '<td><select name="unit[]" class="form-control unit"><option value=""> Zgjidh Njësine </option><option value="cope"> Copë </option>'+
        '<option value="dite">Ditë </option></select></td>'+
        '<td><input type="text" id="cmimi"  class="form-control price" name="price[]" required></td>'+
        '<td><input type="text" class="form-control quantity" name="quantity[] required"></td>'+
        '<td><input type="text" class="form-control amount" name="amount[]" required></td>'+
        '<td><a href="#" class="btn btn-danger a-btn-slide-text remove"><span><strong>x</strong></span>'+
        '</tr>';
    $('.detail').append(vartr);
}
```

I fill the select box with the data from a table using php .
What i'm trying to do is getting the data of the specified service(Sherbimet) while selecting that option in the select box and display these data in the inputs of the specified row(rows are created dynamically).
I've done it for the first row, the data is displayed well, but for the other rows it is changing  result all the inputs of all the rows with the same data.
The code for this looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $(document).on('change','#sh',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var empid = $(this).val();
   

    $.ajax({
       method:"POST",
       url: 'sale_data.php',
       dataType: "JSON",
       data: 'empid='+ empid,
       cache: false,
       success: function(data) {
       
           var a= data.description;
           var b=data.price;
           $('input[name="description[]"]').val(a);
           $('input[name="price[]"]').val(b);
       }
   });
```

});
});

Comment: This should not have `onchange="fillData()"` in the HTML to begin with. You are using jQuery already, so use the methods that provides to add the event handling code as well. (If you don’t want to add an individual handler for every select field you create, then use _event delegation_.) Once you done that, `$(this)` gives you access to the element the event actually occurred upon, and then you can navigate the DOM from there to find the correct related elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1. First of all try cleaning the html code inside the javascript using backticks (``) for comments

```
        function addNewRow() {
            var tableRow = `
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <select 
                            onchange="fillData(this)"  
                            name="service[]" 
                            class="form-control sherbimi" 
                            aria-describedby="llojisherbimit" required>
                            <option selected="selected" value=""> Zgjedh opsionin </option>
                            <option value="5" class="sale-select">5</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                    <td><input type="text" id="pershkrimi" value="" class="form-control" name="description[]" required ></td>
                    <td>
                        <select name="unit[]" class="form-control unit">
                            <option value="">Zgjidh Njësine </option>
                            <option value="cope"> Copë </option>
                            <option value="dite">Ditë </option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                    <td><input type="text" id="cmimi"  class="form-control price" name="price[]" required></td>
                    <td><input type="text" class="form-control quantity" name="quantity[] required"></td>
                    <td><input type="text" class="form-control amount" name="amount[]" required></td>
                    <td><a href="#" class="btn btn-danger a-btn-slide-text remove"><span><strong>x</strong></span></td>
                </tr>
            `
            $('.detail').append(tableRow);
        }
```

> - use proper naming syntax for functions and variables e.g addnewrow to addNewRow, always declare variables with `var`, `const` or `let`.
> - results of php code store in a javascript variable, as the php code will execute only on the server side and if you need something dynamic
>   from php you should use ajax otherwise it will not work. In your case
>   it is working as php its echo-ing out the html code that will be used
>   for preparing the results of a function.
> - the problem with your code is that you are not passing the certain elemenet that is being changed but rather you are trying to select the
>   element via class selectors, that one is always defaulting to the
>   first selector instead what you need to do is:

1. on the html side call the function fillData with the paramete `this` like:

   ```
    <table class="table table-responsive table-bordered table-hover">
           <thead>
              <th>Shërbimi</th>
              <th>Përshkrimi</th>
              <th>Njësia</th>
              <th>Çmimi</th>
              <th>Sasia</th>
              <th>Total</th>
              <th>
                <button id="add" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="addNewRow()">+</button></th>
           </thead>
           <tbody class="detail">
              <tr>
                 <td width="25%">
                    <select name="service[]" onchange="fillData(this)" class="form-control sherbimi"  aria-describedby="llojisherbimit" required>
                       <option selected="selected" value="" disabled="disabled">Zgjedh Shërbimin</option>
                       <option value='1'  class='sale-select'>1</option>
                       <option value='2'  class='sale-select'>2</option>
                       <option value='3'  class='sale-select'>3</option>
                    </select>
                    <div class="invalid-feedback">
                       Ju lutem plotësoni shërbimin.
                    </div>
                 </td>
                 <td width="30%" >
                    <input type="text" id="pershkrimi" value="" class="form-control" name="description[]" required >
                    <div class="invalid-feedback">
                       Ju lutem plotësoni përshkrimin.
                    </div>
                 </td>
                 <td width="15%">
                    <select name="unit[]" class="form-control" aria-describedby="llojinjesis" required>
                       <option value="">Zgjedh Njësin</option>
                       <option value='cope'> Copë </option>
                       <option value='dite'> Ditë </option>
                    </select>
                    <div class="invalid-feedback">
                       Ju lutem plotësoni njësin.
                    </div>
                 </td>
                 <td width="10%"  >
                    <input type="text" id="cmimi"  class="form-control price" name="price[]" required>
                    <div class="invalid-feedback">
                       Ju lutem plotësoni çmimin.
                    </div>
                 </td>
                 <td width="10%">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control quantity" name="quantity[]" required>
                    <div class="invalid-feedback">
                       Ju lutem plotësoni sasinë.
                    </div>
                 </td>
                 <td width="10%">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control amount" name="amount[]" required>
                    <div class="invalid-feedback">
                       Ju lutem plotësoni totalin.
                    </div>
                 </td>
                 <td>
                    <!-- <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger a-btn-slide-text remove">
                       <span><strong>x</strong></span></a> -->
                 </td>
              </tr>
           </tbody>
           <tfoot>
              <th></th>
              <th></th>
              <th></th>
              <th></th>
              <th></th>
              <th style="text-align:center;" class="total">0<b></b></th>
              <th></th>
           </tfoot>
        </table>
   ```
2. also change the addNewRow function so it includes this variable (dont forget to use your version as I removed the php stuff from here):

   ```
       function addNewRow() {
           var tableRow = `
               <tr>
                   <td>
                       <select 
                           onchange="fillData(this)"  
                           name="service[]" 
                           class="form-control sherbimi" 
                           aria-describedby="llojisherbimit" required>
                           <option selected="selected" value=""> Zgjedh opsionin </option>
                           <option value="5" class="sale-select">5</option>
                       </select>
                   </td>
                   <td><input type="text" id="pershkrimi" value="" class="form-control" name="description[]" required ></td>
                   <td>
                       <select name="unit[]" class="form-control unit">
                           <option value="">Zgjidh Njësine </option>
                           <option value="cope"> Copë </option>
                           <option value="dite">Ditë </option>
                       </select>
                   </td>
                   <td><input type="text" id="cmimi"  class="form-control price" name="price[]" required></td>
                   <td><input type="text" class="form-control quantity" name="quantity[] required"></td>
                   <td><input type="text" class="form-control amount" name="amount[]" required></td>
                   <td><a href="#" class="btn btn-danger a-btn-slide-text remove"><span><strong>x</strong></span></td>
               </tr>
           `
           $('.detail').append(tableRow);
       }
   ```
3. and then filldata function:

   ```
        function fillData(element) {

                var empid = element.value

                $.ajax({
                    method:"POST",
                    url: 'sale_data.php',
                    dataType: "JSON",
                    data: 'empid='+ empid,
                    success: function(data) {
                        $('input[name="description[]"]').val(data.description);
                        $('input[name="price[]"]').val(data.price);
                    }
            });
        }
   ```